# How to cache videos in Django?

Tags: django, caching, video, preload

How to cache videos in django? Like in youtube, preloading video while user watches it. I've searched on about this, google showed something about Redis, Memcached and etc. Can you provide some examples on how to do such thing?

Answer (score 0):

"preloading video while user watches it" ==> you should do it in **front end**, it isn't in charge of back end and django

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If you would like to express your own opinion rather than providing a direct solution, put it as a comment instead of an answer. You might wanna read - [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).